# How to set two foreign keys from one table?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I have two tables USERS and FRIENDSHIPS,what i need is to record friendships between users in FRIENDSHIPS table.I think i should use two foreign keys from USERS table one for the primary user and  the other for user he is friends with.I just started learning so i only know to use Workbench to some extent.My question is how do you set up two foreign keys from the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the foreign keys pointing the wrong way.

A "user" can have multiple "friendship" (zero, one or more), but a "friendship" can be related to only two "user".

Add two constraints on your "friendship" table, assuming that your two columns are named `from_userid` and `to_userid`

```
CONSTRAINT FK_friendship_from FOREIGN KEY (from_userid) REFERENCES user (id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

CONSTRAINT FK_friendship_to FOREIGN KEY (to_userid) REFERENCES user (id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

In case this wasn't clear, you do NOT add a foreign key to the "user" table. The foreign keys should  point from the child table to the parent table.

As an example:

```
user
id name   
-- ------
 2 Peter
 3 Paul
 5 Mary

friendship
from_userid to_userid
----------- ---------
          2         3
          2         5
          3         3
```

According to the contents of these tables, Peter (`id=2`) has two friends, Paul (`id=3`) and Mary (`id=5`). And Paul (`id=3`) has one friend Paul (himself, `id=3`)